# batch response: dial tcp: lookup gitlab.com: no such host

Tags: git, gitlab, git-push, git-pull, git-lfs

If I'm going to push a small private repository, every thing's OK

```
Sepideh@DESKTOP-M232FOC MINGW64 /e/Test_gitlab (master)
$ git push -u origin --all
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 236 bytes | 78.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To gitlab.com:abadpours/test.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.

Sepideh@DESKTOP-M232FOC MINGW64 /e/Test_gitlab (master)
$ git push -u origin --tags
Everything up-to-date
```

But for a big (1.94 GB), LFS-enabled private repository, I'll have the following:

```
Sepideh@DESKTOP-M232FOC MINGW64 /e/MSc_Thesis (master)
$ git config lfs.https://gitlab.com/abadpours/msc_thesis.git/info/lfs.locksverify true

Sepideh@DESKTOP-M232FOC MINGW64 /e/MSc_Thesis (master)
$ git push -u origin --all
Connection to gitlab.com closed by remote host.
Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/4), 62 MB | 109 KB/s, done
batch response: Post https://gitlab.com/abadpours/msc_thesis.git/info/lfs/objects/batch: dial tcp: lookup gitlab.com: no such host
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:abadpours/msc_thesis.git'
```

The result is the same since yesterday. Are there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: Commenting because I don't think it's a real answer, although it may help someone. But I was facing the same problem consistently. After changing my connection from WiFi to cable, the issue disappeared and never happened again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HTTPS URL` should be used instead of `SSH URL`

[image]

Comment: It shouldn't matter. If you push/pull via SSH but have LFS, then GitLab and the Git client will intelligently handle LFS files over HTTPS anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You are using an SSH URL for your remote repository: `git@gitlab.com:abadpours/xxx`

That means you are not concerned with an HTTP proxy.

But the Git LFS objects are using an HTTPS URL, which means, if you are behing a proxy, you might have some issue, like [`git-lfs/git-lfs` issue 1424](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1424).

> One is that we don't support socks5h, which is known and is a limitation in Go. The other is that we seem to prepend `http://` to the proxy if it doesn't contain it, which is probably not a good idea if we want SOCKS support to work.

Or: [`git-lfs/git-lfs` issue 3551](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3551)

> I cannot get git lfs fetch to work behind my corporate proxy. Same error when it's configured with either the env var `http_proxy` or `git.config http.proxy`.
>
> I looked at the proxy server logs with a sysadmin and **it appears git-lfs is not even adressing the proxy, but trying to access the network directly (hence the DNS error)**.  Regular git and other network activities work fine in this configuration.

In that latter case, if was [the proxy configuration](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3551#issuecomment-469720939) (`http://username:password@host.fr:8050`) which was not [properly percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters).

---

As [Drew Blessing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5385187/drew-blessing) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57229595/batch-response-dial-tcp-lookup-gitlab-com-no-such-host/57229860?noredirect=1#comment101154647_57229860):

> It may be a good test to try to clone the project via HTTPS in a different location.
> This would rule out a general problem with connecting to GitLab.com via 443 - `git clone https://gitlab.com/group/project.git`.
> If that doesn't work then there's definitely a problem with network, proxy, etc.

Comment: OK, but this is the URL that [gitlab has suggested](http://s8.picofile.com/file/8367937850/Untitled.png). Can I just [change this URL](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-a-remotes-url#switching-remote-urls-from-ssh-to-https)?

Comment: @SepidehAbadpour No, I meant you can check if you are behind a proxy, and what kind of URL you have used for your proxy (like one with username:password in it)

Comment: [where should I check then?](http://s8.picofile.com/file/8367941934/Untitled.png)

Comment: As shown in the answer: your http_proxy environment variable or git config http.proxy.

Comment: well in the photo that I linked in the previous comment, it seems that I'm not using a proxy. Also I get no result for the commands `$ git config http.proxy` or `$ git config --global --get http.proxy`

Comment: @SepidehAbadpour Check your credential manager (since `git config credential.helper` returns `manager`): do you have the right credentials for gitlab.com in there?

Comment: [Here](http://s9.picofile.com/file/8367968342/Capture.JPG) is the result of the command in git bash `$ git config credential.helper
manager
` Yes it returns manager. And about gitlab account yes I'm the only user of this personal account

Comment: @VonC: the issue you linked (3551) was closed with a new syntax you can now configure: instead of `https://...` you can (apparently) configure `socks5://...`. Not sure which version of Git-LFS this is, though.

Comment: @torek I agree. I was more interested in this issue about the URL misconfiguration (username / password part of the URL, and not percent encoded)

Comment: It may be a good test to try to clone the project via HTTPS in a different location. This would rule out a general problem with connecting to GitLab.com via 443 - `git clone https://gitlab.com/group/project.git`. If that doesn't work then there's definitely a problem with network, proxy, etc.